# Error in posting data to php in my ajax code

Tags: php, ajax

I have been trying to validate the email address typed in an input field using jQuery and Ajax. It seems that the jQuery addClass and removeClass in my validation PHP does not seem to apply to the main PHP file.

Here is my code:-

```
<table cellspacing="10px" cellspacing="5px" class="sign_up_table">

    <tr>
        <td>
        <input class="ui_input2 no_space inpt1913" id="input_email" type="email" name="i_email" style="height:25px; width:300px; font-size:16px;" required />
        </td>
        <td id="input_email_error">
        <img src="img/a_loader.gif" id="a_loader_i" style="display:none; position:relative; top: 2px;" />
        </td>
</table>
```

My jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#input_email').on('input',function(e){
            var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
            var val_i_email = $("#input_email").val();

            var empty = false;
            $('#input_email').each(function() {
                if (val_i_email < 5 || !emailReg.test(val_i_email)) {
                    empty = true;
                }
            });

            if (empty) {
                $(this).addClass("invalid");
                $(this).removeClass("valid");

                $email_valid = false;

                    } else {
            var i_email = $("#input_email").val();
            $('#a_loader_i').show();

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/script/validate_email.php',
            data: {i_email:i_email},
            cache: false,
            success: function(){
                $("#a_loader_i").hide();

                $email_valid = true;
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
// include pdo config
include_once ('config.php');

    // store the values submitted by form in variable
    $email=$_POST['i_email'];

    // query
    foreach($pdo->query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email='$email'") as $row); {
        if ($email == $row['Email']) {
            echo "<script>
                    $('#input_email_error').append('This email has already been taken');
                    $('#input_email').addClass('invalid');
                    $('#input_email').removeClass('valid');
                    $('#a_loader_i').hide();
                  </script>";

        }else{
            echo "<script>
                    $('#input_email').addClass('valid');
                    $('#input_email').removeClass('invalid');
                    $('#a_loader_i').hide();
                  </script>";
        }
    }

$pdo = null;
```

Comment: `data: {input_email:i_email},` where is `i_email` defined? i can only see `val_i_email`

Comment: The post has been edited ...

Comment: Do console logs give errors? If not check "Network" in Google Chrome "Inspect Element"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are returning HTML in your ajax call that you are expecting to get called.  Instead of doing that, have you php return a JSON encoded true/false that you check and then have the success callback do the logic that you are attempting in your php.

In the javascript do:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/script/validate_email.php',
            data: {'i_email':i_email},
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                if(data.valid) {
                    $('#input_email').addClass('valid');
                    $('#input_email').removeClass('invalid');
                    $('#a_loader_i').hide();
                } else {
                    $('#input_email_error').append('This email has already been taken');
                    $('#input_email').addClass('invalid');
                    $('#input_email').removeClass('valid');
                    $('#a_loader_i').hide();
                }
            });
```

And in the php:

```
 if ($email == $row['Email']) {
      $valid = false;
 } else {
      $valid = true;
 }

 echo json_encode(array('valid' => $valid));
```

You have the php return if the email is valid or not and the page itself decides what to do with that.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get you as I am a newbie

Comment: added code to the answer.  You should be changing the fields in the JavaScript not in the PHP.

Comment: Also, if you look at his query, he's missing a string operator.  Also, I don't see anywhere he's prepped the $pdo, so there might be issues there.  Amend your query to `"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email='".$email."'"`

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your config.php, i can't reall see the full picture, but i'm guessing that you should `echo json_encode($response);` in you php file

`$response` should contain something like:

if email accepted:

```
$response = array(
        'success' => true,
        'note' => "Accepted"
    );
```

or if email exist/invalid:

```
$response = array(
        'success' => false,
        'note' => "This email has already been taken"
    );
```

and then in success in jquery:

```
    success: function(response){
        if(response.success){
            $('#input_email').addClass('valid');
            $('#input_email').removeClass('invalid');

        } else {
            $('#input_email').addClass('invalid');
            $('#input_email').removeClass('valid');

        }
        $('#input_email_error').append(response.note);
        $('#a_loader_i').hide();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

`$email=$_POST['i_email'];` in your PHP code looks for the item named `i_email` in your post values.  If you could see the string, it would look like `i_email=sting@mail.com` (probably url encoded, too).

In your AJAX, you are defining the key as the same as your value.  So

```
else {
        var i_email = $("#input_email").val(); //You define your variable.

        $('#a_loader_i').show();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/script/validate_email.php',
        data: {i_email:i_email},  //Outputs as 'you@mail.com:you@mail.com'
        cache: false,
        success: function(){
            $("#a_loader_i").hide();

            $email_valid = true;
            }
        });
    }
```

You would want to change i_email:i_email to `email:i_email` or something similiar, and then `$_POST['email']` in your PHP.

Comment: It will not output the first i_email as 'you@mail.com', it will output as i_email.  The value before the semicolon is a literal for a query string variable.

Comment: You are correct. In whatever de-caffinated stuper that spurned this bad answer, I'm assuming I was trying to point out the changing some naming conventions might help trace the issue.